# how to include a point on the same split line in kd-tree implementation

Tags: python, kdtree

I am following a python code of KD Tree implementation from https://rosettacode.org/wiki/K-d_tree, and the code is like below:

```
from random import seed, random
from time import clock
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import namedtuple
from math import sqrt
from copy import deepcopy


def sqd(p1, p2):
    return sum((c1 - c2) ** 2 for c1, c2 in zip(p1, p2))


class KdNode(object):
    __slots__ = ("dom_elt", "split", "left", "right")

    def __init__(self, dom_elt, split, left, right):
        self.dom_elt = dom_elt
        self.split = split
        self.left = left
        self.right = right


class Orthotope(object):
    __slots__ = ("min", "max")

    def __init__(self, mi, ma):
        self.min, self.max = mi, ma


class KdTree(object):
    __slots__ = ("n", "bounds")

    def __init__(self, pts, bounds):
        def nk2(split, exset):
            if not exset:
                return None
            exset.sort(key=itemgetter(split))
            print('-------------------------------')
            print('set: ',exset, 'split: ',split)
            m = len(exset) // 2
            d = exset[m]
            print('pivot point:', d, 'm: ',m)
            while m + 1 < len(exset) and exset[m + 1][split] == d[split]:
                m += 1
            print('pivot point:', d, 'm: ',m)
            s2 = (split + 1) % len(d)  # cycle coordinates
            return KdNode(d, split, nk2(s2, exset[:m]),
                                    nk2(s2, exset[m + 1:]))
        self.n = nk2(0, pts)
        self.bounds = bounds


if __name__ == "__main__":
    seed(1)
    P = lambda *coords: list(coords)
    kd1 = KdTree([P(2, 3), P(5, 4), P(9, 6), P(4, 7), P(8, 1), P(7, 2)],
                  Orthotope(P(0, 0), P(10, 10)))
```

The result is like this:

```
-------------------------------
set:  [[2, 3], [4, 7], [5, 4], [7, 1], [7, 2], [9, 6]] split:  0
pivot point: [7, 1] m:  3
pivot point: [7, 1] m:  4
-------------------------------
set:  [[7, 1], [2, 3], [5, 4], [4, 7]] split:  1
pivot point: [5, 4] m:  2
pivot point: [5, 4] m:  2
-------------------------------
set:  [[2, 3], [7, 1]] split:  0
pivot point: [7, 1] m:  1
pivot point: [7, 1] m:  1
-------------------------------
set:  [[2, 3]] split:  1
pivot point: [2, 3] m:  0
pivot point: [2, 3] m:  0
-------------------------------
set:  [[4, 7]] split:  0
pivot point: [4, 7] m:  0
pivot point: [4, 7] m:  0
-------------------------------
set:  [[9, 6]] split:  1
pivot point: [9, 6] m:  0
pivot point: [9, 6] m:  0
```

I slightly changed the example, P(8,1) to P(7,1) *(I drew the points below)* and found out that then P(7,2) will not be made to a KdNode since the first pivot point is (7,1) and that KdNode will split the set to {[2,3], [4,7], [5,4], [7,1]} AND {[9,6]} which will make P(7,2) to be disappeared, according to the code.

[image]

I wonder if there are another points on the same split line of pivoting point, (here, vertical line crossing (7,1)) which set will P(7,2) should be included and when does it have to be made as a KdNode?

Thank you for reading and help will be so much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Change of code

`return KdNode(d, split, self.nk2(s2, exset[:m]),self.nk2(s2, exset[m + 1:]))`

to

`return KdNode(exset[m], split, self.nk2(s2, exset[:m]),self.nk2(s2, exset[m + 1:]))`

is working for including the missing point, although split looks quite strange for me. I will still look forward to hearing better answer though! thank you!